# Using variables in re.findall() regex function

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of regex patterns like *k[a-z]p[a-z]+a* 
and a list of words that can fit into these patterns. Now, the problem is that,
when I use:

```
re.findall(r'k[a-z]p[a-z]+a', list)
```

Everything works properly, but when I replace the raw expression with a variable like:

```
pattern = "r'" + pattern + "'"
```

and then try:

```
re.findall(pattern, list)
```

or

```
re.findall(str(pattern), list)
```

It no longer works. How could I fix it?

Thanks!
Spike

Comment: Are you intending to match your words with the pattern `r'k[a-z]p[a-z]+a'`? What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? This question is fairly obscure in its expected resolution

Comment: Hi, welcome to [SO]! When you have a moment, please take the [tour] and pay special attention to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: `pattern  = re.escape(pattern)`

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking it. The `r` prefix is not part of the pattern string itself, it merely indicates that *the following string* should not use escape codes for certain characters.

This will work without adjusting your pattern:

```
re.findall(pattern, list)
```

If your `pattern` contains characters that do not need escaping (as they do not), you can add the prefix `r` to the pattern definition. Suppose you want to search for a different regex, then use

```
pattern = r'k\wp\wa'
re.findall(pattern, list)
```

and you don't need to escape it. Since `pattern` in itself is a perfectly ordinary string, you can concatenate it with other strings:

```
start = 'a'
middle = 'b'
end = 'c'
pattern = a + r'\w' + b + r'\w' + c
re.findall(pattern, list)
```